Faster way to retrieve/process images on ESP8266?
I am currently making a small piece of hardware to go on my desk using an ESP8266 (specifically for the wifi capabilities), and having an issue with retrieving images from Spotify's API taking too long, often up to 4-5 seconds for a 25kb image.
I have tried to find any possible asynchronous solutions to prevent blocking for the rest of my program, but there seems to be no native support. I have also considered progressive rendering, which proved to end with a lack of support. Basically each time I skip a song the screen connected to my ESP draws the album image, song name, and artist. However, each time I skip it currently downloads the album and blocks any other part of my program from executing.
Here is the specific function:
bool getTrackInfo(){
    unsigned long startTime, endTime;

    startTime = millis();  // Start timing
    
    String url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing";
    https.useHTTP10(true);
    https.begin(*client, url);
    String auth = "Bearer " + String(accessToken);
    https.addHeader("Authorization", auth);
    
    int httpResponseCode = https.GET();
    bool success = false;
    String songId = "";
    bool refresh = false;
    
    endTime = millis();  // Time after request
    Serial.print("Time taken for GET request: ");
    Serial.println(endTime - startTime);

    // Check if the request was successful
    if (httpResponseCode == 200) {
        startTime = millis();  // Start timing for data processing
        
        String currentSongProgress = getValue(https, "progress_ms");
        currentSongPositionMs = currentSongProgress.toFloat();
        
        String imageLink = "";
        while (imageLink.indexOf("image") == -1) {
            String height = getValue(https, "height");
            if (height.toInt() > 300) {
                imageLink = "";
                continue;
            }
            imageLink = getValue(https, "url");
        }
        
        String albumName = getValue(https, "name");
        String artistName = getValue(https, "name");
        String songDuration = getValue(https, "duration_ms");
        currentSong.durationMs = songDuration.toInt();
        String songName = getValue(https, "name");
        songId = getValue(https, "uri");
        String isPlay = getValue(https, "is_playing");
        isPlaying = isPlay == "true";
        
        songId = songId.substring(15, songId.length() - 1);
        
        endTime = millis();  // Time after data processing
        Serial.print("Time taken for data processing: ");
        Serial.println(endTime - startTime);
        
        https.end();
        
        startTime = millis();  // Start timing for image download
        
        if (songId != currentSong.Id) {
            if (SPIFFS.exists("/albumArt.jpg")) {
                SPIFFS.remove("/albumArt.jpg");
            }
            
            bool loaded_ok = getFile(imageLink.substring(1, imageLink.length() - 1).c_str(), "/albumArt.jpg");
            Serial.println("Image load was: ");
            Serial.println(loaded_ok);
            
            endTime = millis();  // Time after image download
            Serial.print("Time taken for image download: ");
            Serial.println(endTime - startTime);
            
            refresh = true;
            tft.fillScreen(TFT_BLACK);
        }
        
        currentSong.album = albumName.substring(1, albumName.length() - 1);
        currentSong.artist = artistName.substring(1, artistName.length() - 1);
        currentSong.song = songName.substring(1, songName.length() - 1);
        currentSong.Id = songId;
        success = true;
    } else {
        Serial.print("Error getting track info: ");
        Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
        https.end();
    }
    
    if (success) {
        startTime = millis();  // Start timing for screen update
        
        drawScreen(refresh);
        
        endTime = millis();  // Time after screen update
        Serial.print("Time taken for screen update: ");
        Serial.println(endTime - startTime);
        
        lastSongPositionMs = currentSongPositionMs;
    }
    return success;
}
bool drawScreen(bool fullRefresh = false) {
    // Declare variables for rectangle dimensions
    int rectWidth = 160;
    int rectHeight = 13.33;
    
    if(fullRefresh) {
        tft.fillScreen(TFT_BLACK);

        // Draw text before downloading the image
        int artistTextWidth = tft.textWidth(currentSong.artist);
        int artistX = (tft.width() - artistTextWidth) / 2;
        int artistY = 180; // Y coordinate for artist text
        int songTextWidth = tft.textWidth(currentSong.song);
        int songX = (tft.width() - songTextWidth) / 2;
        int songY = 210;

        tft.setTextSize(2);
        tft.setTextDatum(MC_DATUM);
        tft.setTextWrap(true);
        tft.setCursor(artistX, artistY);
        printSplitString(currentSong.artist, 20, 85);

        tft.setCursor(songX, songY);
        printSplitString(currentSong.song, 20, 110);

        tft.drawRoundRect(
            tft.width() / 2 - rectWidth / 2,
            250,
            rectWidth,
            rectHeight,
            4,
            TFT_DARKGREEN
        );
    }

    // Handle image download after text has been drawn
    if (fullRefresh) {
        if (SPIFFS.exists("/albumArt.jpg")) { 
            TJpgDec.setSwapBytes(true);
            TJpgDec.setJpgScale(2);
         

            int imageWidth = 300;
            int imageHeight = 300;

            int x = (tft.width() - imageWidth) /2;
           

            
            TJpgDec.drawFsJpg(x, 10, "/albumArt.jpg");
            
        } else {
            TJpgDec.setSwapBytes(false);
            TJpgDec.setJpgScale(1);
            TJpgDec.drawFsJpg(0, 0, "/Angry.jpg");
        }
    } else {
        if (lastSongPositionMs > currentSongPositionMs) {
            tft.fillSmoothRoundRect(
                tft.width() / 2 - rectWidth / 2 + 2,
                250 + 2,
                rectWidth - 4,
                rectHeight - 4,
                10,
                TFT_BLACK
            );
            lastSongPositionMs = currentSongPositionMs;
        }
        tft.fillSmoothRoundRect(
            tft.width() / 2 - rectWidth / 2 + 2,
            250 + 2,
            rectWidth * (currentSongPositionMs / currentSong.durationMs) - 4,
            rectHeight - 4,
            10,
            TFT_GREEN
        );
    }

    return true;
}

I have added logging to diagnose where the time is being hogged and it is really only a problem at download:
Time taken for GET request: 899
Time taken for data processing: 172
Time taken for screen update: 36
Time taken for GET request: 867
Time taken for data processing: 159
Downloading /albumArt.jpg from https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02d41fec800fa501c5bc623083
[HTTP] begin...
[HTTP] GET...
[HTTP] GET... code: 200

[HTTP] connection closed or file end.
Image load was: 
1
Time taken for image download: 20654
Time taken for screen update: 477
Time taken for GET request: 1025


as you can see all other operations are rather stable, but the image download in this case--albeit higher than normal here, but not a one off--is quite high taking nearly 20 seconds just to download a 300x300 JPEG.
So my question is, is there a better method for this or is this board simply limited in its capabiltiies?
